# Last 5 entries or more depending on where

Tags: mysql

I want to run a query where the last 5 entries are always returned, which is simple: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5`. But I want to get more than 5 if a certain condition applies, which by itself would simply be something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field > value`. Is there a way to do this as a single query or do I have to run 2?

Comment: What is the benefit of making it as a single query?

Comment: Nope. You will have a convoluted SQL instead of two simple queries.  In all probability the combined query will run longer.

Comment: With all due respect, you don't know the code. 1 SQL statement where I could just loop over all returned entries instead of having extra logic to process 2 sets while ignoring duplicates, merging, and re-sorting would greatly simplify my code, even if the SQL statement were more difficult.

Comment: You may want to clarify your question and provide sample data and the expected result.  It's not clear if you intend to use the two queries as alternatives or in combination.  I assumed the former.

Comment: Combination. I want the most recent 5 no matter what, in addition to any others that match certain conditions. There is an autonumber field named id for ordering. Just because the most recent 5 are chosen, doesn't mean they necessarily meet the conditions though

Comment: Then `UNION` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe with `UNION`?. Like:

```
(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE field > value)
```